# How to bind the event Kendo grid PopUp mode?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My requirement i want to do the calculation in Kendo Grid While Clicking the Add New Record or Edit in Popup mode. Currently i am not able to catch the Kendo Grid Popup event.
 But i can able to catch the event outside using html on chaning event. It's working but i need to add the this functionality in inside grid like how we are binding event/methode to save, remove ,cancel.
 I tried using change event but it is working inline of the grid but it's not working in popup mode. Please look at my Dojo link. http://dojo.telerik.com/AtebI/10

Acutally i am generating grid on the fly(dynamically). So i have to bind the event before Creating/rendering.

Anyone help me to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind the Kendo grid Popup event when editing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827450/how-to-bind-the-kendo-grid-popup-event-when-editing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid edit event is fired when user opens row edit on popup editor and also when creating new row.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit

Comment: Thank you! and I have another one issue. I can able to do the  calculation in popup mode. But It is not updating back to grid. Can you please help me to resolve this. Please have look my code.  http://dojo.telerik.com/uPIVe

Comment: Put new calculated value to model using set function. It will update the value also in input. http://dojo.telerik.com/uPIVe/3

Comment: And you should edit your datasource schema. Define those values as numeric, so user can not type nothing else but numbers.

Comment: Yeah. I have to give numeric . Thank You

Comment: I changed all the three columns to number but it not updating the Amount when ever the changes happening on Quantity or Rate. When i clicking the Amount numeric text box then the calculated value is updating. Please help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100891/discussion-between-japi-and-bagya).

Comment: Please check this links http://dojo.telerik.com/uPIVe.  The calculated value working for existing record but it's not working for When i add new records. Please check Amount not calculating by default.